# Stack Buffer overflow behaviour

Tags: c++, c, buffer-overflow

Does declaring a variable after a buffer in a function make its memory area inaccessible by the buffer? Because I tried doing that and every time I compile the program the buffer can still access it. First address of the buffer is always the lowest possible address of the stack frame.

Does it have to do with the compiler? I'm using gcc.

```
int check_authentication(char *password){
    int demovar;
    char password_buffer[16];
    int auth_flag;

    strcpy(password_buffer,password);
    if(strcmp(password_buffer,"brilling")==0)auth_flag=1;
    if(strcmp(password_buffer,"outgrabe")==0)auth_flag=1;

    return auth_flag;
}
```

Comment: I can't decode your actual question, but the obvious flaw in your code above is that "auth_flag" is not initialized.

Comment: There's no guarantee the variables will be placed in any particular order.  You'll need to experiment with adding other variables and reordering them.

Comment: As others have noted, the compiler is at liberty to arrange the variables in whatever memory location it decides. Compiler optimizations may result in certain _somewhat predictable behavior_, but again it's nothing you can know with certainly until you look at the produced assembly, and definitely nothing you can control in C without directly emitting assembly.

Answer (score 7):

First:

The C standard does **not** tell anything about the location of your variables. The C standard doesn't even say that they are on a (call) stack. So your variables can be anywhere in memory (or they can not even be in memory).

A stack is an implementation specific thing that is never ever mentioned by the standard. Most (if not all) implementations use a stack but still there is no way to tell from the C code how variables will be located on the stack. It's an implementation thing - it's decided by your compiler.

Second:

C has no overflow protection what so ever. If you copy more into `password_buffer` than it can hold (16 char in this example), C will not warn you. It's called Undefined Behavior. It means that anything may happen. Maybe your program crash. Maybe it overwrites another variable. Maybe ... whatever. But nothing in C will help you. It's your responsebility to make sure such things doesn't happen.

It's kind of how C works. The programmer is responsible for doing things correctly. There is almost no help in C. The benefit is that there is almost no overhead in C. You win some, you lose some...